# print() and return statements in while loops

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, printing, return

Considering the code below:

```
    MENU = {'sandwich': 10, 'tea': 7, 'pizza': 10, 'soda':3, 'burger': 10}
    
    def restaurant():
        total = 0
        while True:
            order = input('Order: ').lower().strip()
            if not order:
                break
            if order in MENU:
                price = MENU[order]
                total += price
                **return f'{order} is {price}, total is {total}' #will not loop
                print(f'{order} is {price}, total is {total}') #will loop**
            else:
                print(f'Sorry, we are fresh out of {order} today')
        print(f'Your total is {total}')
    
    restaurant()
```

The question is:

Why while loop does not loop through `return` but loops through `print`? I've been learning python but pointed out this occasion only now.

Comment: "return" ends the function and returns a value, "print" just prints values onto the console

Comment: `print` and `return` have nothing in common (the REPL's practice of printing the value of an expression notwithstanding).

Comment: What do you think `return` should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` will stop the execution of the function and returns some value to the calling function. In your case, the string - `f'{order} is {price}, total is {total}'`

`print` will just print the string and doesn't stop the execution of the function.